# R in parallel, parLapply() not returning the same as lapply()

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow, rparallel

I've been tasked with making some code run quicker at work and I have run into a roadblock with parallel computing.  I have an original for loop which I would like to run in parallel.  It seemed easiest to reproduce the code without the for loop and instead use lapply(), however that runs just as long as the loop.  Rewriting the code using parLapply() gives me a much quicker result, albeit a different result than that of lapply() and the original for loop, which are both comparable.  The intent of the program is to calculate cash spreads at each maturity level for individual countries (i.e. a spread curve).

"bonddata.csv" link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/hfcdbryhedpso77/bonddata.csv
"weocountries.csv" link:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/7x15csw7lwwataj/weocountries.csv

Loading in the needed data and libraries:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(Rblpapi)
library(xts)
library(YieldCurve)
library(parallel)
library(snow)
library(countrycode)
library(gridExtra)
library(compare)

#Read in the data
countries<-read.csv("weocountries.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings="")
bonddata <- read.csv("bonddata.csv")
bonddata$iso <- as.character(bonddata$iso)
bonddata$maturity <- as.Date(as.character(bonddata$maturity))
rownames(bonddata) <- as.character(bonddata$X)
bonddata$X <- NULL
bonddata <- na.omit(bonddata)
```

Creating the function to calculate cash spread:

```
calcspreadcurve<-function(data,maturities){
  numbonds<-nrow(data)
  if(numbonds<=3){
    ForceIntercept<-.5*min(data$spread)
    mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
    fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*maturities)+ForceIntercept
    return(fits)
  }
  else {
    mod<-try(Nelson.Siegel(data$spread,12*data$averagelife),TRUE)
    if(is.numeric(mod)){
      fits<-as.vector(NSrates(xts(mod,Sys.Date()),12*maturities))
    } else {
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*maturities)+ForceIntercept
    }       

    if(min(fits)<0){
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*maturities)+ForceIntercept
    } 

    if(mean(fits)>2*mean(data$spread)){
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*maturities)+ForceIntercept
    }

    return(fits)
  }
}

# Calculate standardized USD spread curves for all countries
bondcountries<-unique(bonddata$iso)
maturities<-c(1,2,5,10,20,30,50,100)
```

The original code:

```
#Original for loop
cashspreads<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(bondcountries)){
  curve<-calcspreadcurve(bonddata[bonddata$iso==bondcountries[i],],maturities)
  cashspreads<-rbind(cashspreads,curve)
}
rownames(cashspreads)<-sapply(bondcountries,function(x) countries$ISO3[which(countries$ISO2==x)])
colnames(cashspreads)<-c("1Y","2Y","5Y","10Y","20Y","30Y","50Y","100Y")
```

lapply() code:

```
#What loop is doing (lapply)
cashspreads2 <- t(as.data.frame(lapply(split(bonddata,bonddata$iso),function(data,m=maturities){
  numbonds<-nrow(data)
  if(numbonds<=3){
    ForceIntercept<-.5*min(data$spread)
    mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
    fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    return(fits)
  }
  else {
    mod<-try(Nelson.Siegel(data$spread,12*data$averagelife),TRUE)
    if(is.numeric(mod)){
      fits<-as.vector(NSrates(xts(mod,Sys.Date()),12*m))
    } else {
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    }       
    if(min(fits)<0){
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    } 
    if(mean(fits)>2*mean(data$spread)){
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    }
    return(fits)
  }
})))
rownames(cashspreads2)<-countrycode(rownames(cashspreads2),"iso2c","iso3c")
colnames(cashspreads2) <- c("1Y","2Y","5Y","10Y","20Y","30Y","50Y","100Y")
```

parLapply() code:

```
#Run in parallel (parLapply)
cl <- makeCluster(type="SOCK",detectCores()-1)
cashspreads3 <- t(as.data.frame(parLapply(cl,split(bonddata,bonddata$iso),function(data,m=c(1,2,5,10,20,30,50,100)){
  numbonds<-nrow(data)
  if(numbonds<=3){
    ForceIntercept<-.5*min(data$spread)
    mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
    fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    return(fits)
  }
  else {
    mod<-try(Nelson.Siegel(data$spread,12*data$averagelife),TRUE)
    if(is.numeric(mod)){
      fits<-as.vector(NSrates(xts(mod,Sys.Date()),12*m))
    } else {
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    }       
    if(min(fits)<0){
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    } 
    if(mean(fits)>2*mean(data$spread)){
      ForceIntercept<-.8*mean(data$spread)
      mod<-lm(I(data$spread-ForceIntercept)~0+log(100*data$averagelife))
      fits<-mod$coefficients*log(100*m)+ForceIntercept
    }
    return(fits)
  }
})))
stopCluster(cl)
rownames(cashspreads3)<-countrycode(rownames(cashspreads3),"iso2c","iso3c")
colnames(cashspreads3) <- c("1Y","2Y","5Y","10Y","20Y","30Y","50Y","100Y")
```

Comparison of dataframes:

```
compare(cashspreads[order(rownames(cashspreads)),],cashspreads2[order(rownames(cashspreads2)),])
compare(cashspreads[order(rownames(cashspreads)),],cashspreads3[order(rownames(cashspreads3)),])
```

If the code runs properly for you, the resulting dataframes, "cashspreads" and  "cashspreads2", will not be comparable with dataframe "cashspreads3."

Any idea as to why this doesn't produce the same dataframe?